# How does Laplace Smoothing Effect Prior / Evidence

Tags: statistics, probability, classification, bayesian

I have a probability / stats question related to implementing Naive Bayes Classifiers, in particular about implementing Laplace Smoothing to avoid the Zero count issue and overfitting.

From what Ive read, the basic NBC formula using MLE looks like this:

```
p(C│F_1 ...F_n )=(p(C)p(F_1 |C)...p(F_n |C))/(p(F_1)...p(F_n))
```

However if one of the p(F_i |C) is zero, the whole probability becomes 0.  One solution is Lapace smooth

```
p(F_i│C)~(x_i+k)/(N+kd)
```

Where x_i is the number of times F_i appeared in class C, N is the number of times class C occurred and d is the number of distinct values F_i has been known to take on.

My question is this:

What if anything needs to be done to p(C) in the numerator, and p(F_i) in the denominator?

Answer (score 2):

Let f = (f_1 ... f_n). Laplace smoothing affects the class likelihood term, p(f|C). It does not affect the class prior p(C). It does have an effect on the marginal probability of f, in the sense that:

p(f) = \sum_c p(C) * p(f|C)

Whereby the term p(f|C) is different if you're Laplace smoothing than if you're not. But since the denominator is constant for all C, you shouldn't be bothering to evaluate this anyway.

P.S. This isn't really a programming question!

Comment: Hey thanks, btw, this is coming up in the context of software engineering / machine learning.  For this application, I actually want a probability estimation, not an argmax classification, so is would like to compute the denominator once. Most tutorials assume you want to discard the denominator but it would be useful in this context.  Do you know where you would point me to a complete discussion of implementing smoothing?  Ive started here but dont see a discussion of the class prior or the feature probability.

http://www.inf.u-szeged.hu/~ormandi/ai2/06-naiveBayes-example.pdf

Comment: Take a look at the first couple of pages of the following lecture notes for an explanation of probabilistic classifiers and what the different terms are called: http://www.dcs.gla.ac.uk/~girolami/Machine_Learning_Module_2006/week_4/Lectures/wk_4.pdf. As far as smoothing goes, by far the most elegant way to view it (in my mind) is in a Bayesian context as a prior on the parameters of the likelihood functions p(f|C). You can then view smoothing as MAP estimation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_a_posteriori_estimation), where not smoothing is Maximum Likelihood Estimation